# What's the best way to encrypt a flash drive?

Tags: usb-drive, encryption

The title says it all. Is there a good, *safe*, flash drive encrypt-er?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_flash_drive#Encryption_and_Security) article. I usually use TrueCrypt for things like this - it's really good. Wikipedia also gives some software called FreeOTFE a mention; it's probably worth checking out.

Comment: FreeOTFE won't be any use to me. We have no active W!nd0w5 computers in our house. I'll take a look at TrueCrypt.

Answer (score 3):

`sudo apt-get install cryptsetup` then use disk-utility to create a partition on the drive and make it encrypted.  You will be asked for a passphrase on inserting the flash drive from then on